# Why does isinstance(value, int) return True when value = True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is pretty bizarre...I take user input from the command line and execute parts of my script depending on what that input is. I used ast.literal_eval() in order to determine whether or not the user is inputting an int, a bool, etc. I was having some trouble executing some parts of it, and that lead me to this:

I have a program:

```
value = True
print(type(value))
print(isinstance(value, bool))
print(isinstance(value, int))
print(isinstance(value, float))
print(isinstance(value, str))
```

that returns:

```
<class 'bool'>
True
True
False
False
```

Any idea why isinstance(value, int) is returning True when value is a bool?

Comment: Because in Python, bools are ints.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks!